# What is the best practices for local storage management and data persitence in the client application?

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, couchbase

I'm developing a REST client for medical web-service for both Android and iOS platforms. After reading of different articles and blog posts I understood that I should always persist data in order to increase app speed, user experience, save network resourses and to allow user to work offline with some data. I decided to use local storage based on `Couchbase Lite`. But this question is data storage independend. I'm interesting in the best ways of implementing it. Currently I ended up with the next wokflow:

1. When the user first logs in I fetch some portion of recent data (in my case it is patients' health records and some reports.)
2. Then in background  I populate my storage with the rest of data
3. Syncronize my data on push notifications to always store the last server data copy.

   But I have a few questions : What is the normal size of local storage? May be some time client data can increase a lot - in such case I will delete the oldest data from the device then in order not to exceed some predefined limit? Let's say it is 50 - 100 Mb. Or I should allow user to control this and give him some interface to delete reports, records? Does the workflow I describe correct? Or may be do wrong something from the technical and UX points of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at downloading an index (names and locations of resources, not the actual resource data) which lists all of the available resources. Display the list, and indicate for each item whether it's available locally or not. When selected, display (downloading if required). Allow editing to delete the local copy of the resource (with a select-all button).

As for storage size, this is device dependent. Apps store what data they need. The question is how much data users will be happy for you to save locally. Give them the option. You could also have a settings screen which offers to delete old resources (not accessed recently) when the size gets above XX Mb.

Comment: " downloading an index". So I should donwload not only data but indexes (tehre names, ids as I understood)? What is about storage size?